Reference request for long time asymptotic behavior of the Green's function for the heat equation
Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a bounded domain with a sufficiently "regular" boundary. Then for the heat equation the Green's function for the first boundary problem in cylinder $Q=\Omega\times(0,\infty)$ is
$$
G(x,y,t)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \varphi_i(x)\varphi_i(y)e^{-\lambda_it},
$$
where $\{\lambda_i\}$ and $\{\varphi_i\}$ are the corresponding eigenvalues and eigenfunctions (of norm 1 in $L_2(\Omega)$) of the Dirichlet problem $-\Delta u=\lambda u$ in $\Omega$, $u|_{\partial\Omega}=0$.
From this representation it seems that the estimate
$$
G(x,y,t)\le Ce^{-\lambda_1t},\quad x,y\in\bar \Omega,\ t\ge1,
$$
should hold, but I cannot find this inequality in literature.
What is the least regularity for $\partial\Omega$ for which the it holds?
I can prove it for $\partial\Omega\in C^\infty$, but would prefer to have a reference even for this case.
